# Unicode issue with PyODBC query

Tags: python, sql-server, unicode, pyodbc

I'm having trouble querying my MSSQL server using PyODBC.

The reason I believe is the fact that I have columns that are named using unicode. The columns come from pivoting a single column in my main data.

The column in question is "afkastningsgrad_primær_drift"

Any idea how I might be able to run this query? (building a view on the server and renaming the column is not an option due to my lack of server ownership)

SQL:

```
WITH dataTable AS (
    SELECT 
        KredsEjdNr, Navn, Vaerdi
    FROM qryEjendomsData

    WHERE 
        RegnskabsAar = 2016 
        AND Projekt = 1710
        AND Navn IN (
            'ekm_ko' , 'afkastningsgrad_primær_drift', 'fremst_pris_maelk'
        )
    GROUP BY KredsEjdNr, Navn, Vaerdi
), 
pivotData AS (

    SELECT * 
    FROM dataTable
    PIVOT
        (
            SUM(Vaerdi)
            FOR[Navn] IN (
                [ekm_ko], [afkastningsgrad_primær_drift], [fremst_pris_maelk]
            )
        )
    AS pivotTable
)

SELECT 
    CAST([KredsEjdNr] AS NVARCHAR) AS [kredsEjdNr], 
    CAST(ekm_ko AS int) AS [EKM pr ko],
    [afkastningsgrad_primær_drift] as [Afkastningsgrad],
    [fremst_pris_maelk] AS [Fremstillingspris pr. kg EKM]
 from pivotData
 where [ekm_ko] IS NOT NULL and [fremst_pris_maelk] IS NOT NULL
 order by kredsEjdNr
```

Python code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
connectionstring = 'DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER=server;DATABASE=database;UID=%s;PWD=%s' %(usr,pswd)
conn = pyodbc.connect(connectionstring)
cursor = conn.cursor()
dataList = cursor.execute(unicode(sql)).fetchall()
```

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "data.py", line 84, in
>   
>       dataList = cursor.execute(unicode(sql)).fetchall() UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position
>   183: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Hmm had to .decode('utf-8) my query to make it work, haven't done that in a while...

Comment: Which `pyodbc.version` are you using?

Comment: Im using version 4.0.16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not with Unicode characters in column names, but with non-ASCII *bytes* in `str` variables under Python2. When a pyodbc `.execute` call receives command text as a `str` it tries to process it using the default encoding, which is 'ascii' for Python2.

The following test code

```python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
print("sys.getdefaultencoding() is '{0}'".format(sys.getdefaultencoding()))
import pyodbc

cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=SQLmyDb", autocommit=True)
crsr = cnxn.cursor()

# setup test environment
crsr.execute(u"CREATE TABLE #tmp (afkastningsgrad_primær_drift INT)")
crsr.execute(u"INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (1)")

print('')
print('Test_1: "SELECT * ..." as str')
sql = "SELECT * FROM #tmp"
print("  sql: " + repr(sql))
crsr.execute(sql)
print("    column name from result set: " + repr(crsr.description[0][0]))

print('')
print('Test_2: "SELECT colname ..." as str')
sql = "SELECT afkastningsgrad_primær_drift FROM #tmp"
print("  sql: " + repr(sql))
try:
    crsr.execute(sql)
    print("    OK")
except UnicodeDecodeError as ude:
    print("    UnicodeDecodeError: " + str(ude))

print('')
print('Test_3: "SELECT colname ..." as unicode')
sql = sql.decode('utf-8')
print("  sql: " + repr(sql))
try:
    crsr.execute(sql)
    print("    OK")
except Exception as ex:
    print("    Exception: " + str(ex))

cnxn.close()
```

produces

```
sys.getdefaultencoding() is 'ascii'

Test_1: "SELECT * ..." as str
  sql: 'SELECT * FROM #tmp'
    column name from result set: u'afkastningsgrad_prim\xe6r_drift'

Test_2: "SELECT colname ..." as str
  sql: 'SELECT afkastningsgrad_prim\xc3\xa6r_drift FROM #tmp'
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 27: ordinal not in range(128)

Test_3: "SELECT colname ..." as unicode
  sql: u'SELECT afkastningsgrad_prim\xe6r_drift FROM #tmp'
    OK
```

Test_1 shows that a column name with Unicode characters is correctly returned as a `unicode` object.

Test_2 shows that the default Python2 encoding ('ascii') chokes on a `str` that contains UTF-8 bytes greater than 0x7F.

Test_3 shows that no error occurs if we use `.decode` to convert the `str` (containing UTF-8 bytes) into a proper `unicode` object which we then pass to the `.execute` method.

Comment: If you're using UTF-8, Python 3 will make your life a *lot* easier. :)